# Devise upgrade from 1.1.5 to 1.4.5 causes Wrong Number of Arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I just upgraded from Devise 1.1.5 to 1.4.5 to use with Rails 3.1 (1.1.5 seems to cause a bcrypt gem version problem).

Now user_signed_in? throws " wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)"

```
Stack trace is:
devise (1.4.5) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:89:in `serialize_from_session'
devise (1.4.5) lib/devise/rails/warden_compat.rb:27:in `deserialize'
warden (1.0.5) lib/warden/session_serializer.rb:31:in `fetch'
warden (1.0.5) lib/warden/proxy.rb:182:in `user'
warden (1.0.5) lib/warden/proxy.rb:278:in `_perform_authentication'
warden (1.0.5) lib/warden/proxy.rb:90:in `authenticate'
devise (1.4.5) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:48:in `current_user'
devise (1.4.5) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:44:in `user_signed_in?'
app/controllers/main_controller.rb:24:in `index'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
.....
```

Anyone experiencing this?

Comment: I've got this issue too. It looks like it's an issue with existing sessions; I open up an Incognito window and everything's fine. I've tried both `rake tmp:clear` and `User.all.map { |u| u.forget_me! }` with no luck.

Comment: I managed to hack it by changing my cookie session key in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`.

Comment: didn't work for me. instead of `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)` now it says `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ran `rake tmp:clear` and changed the name of my session in `session_store.rb`

`Woodhack::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_NEW_NAME_HERE_session'`

Comment: Yeah looks like this probably was the problem.  I hacked the serialize_from_session method a little just to see what was going on, then reinstalled the original 1.4.5 gem and everything works fine.

Comment: Jepp, changing the session name is the way to go if you use cookie based sessions! rake tmp:clear has no effect in this case IMHO.

Comment: Why the heck is this necessary?  I like the name of my old session better.

Comment: ctilley79, obviously the data format is changed and the updated Devise cannot correctly use old data. You need to somehow invalidate the old sessions data for all users currently logged in. There are two ways - either change the name of session so that old data will be ignored, or change the token as suggested below - that will make the data invalid and force users to relogin (it could also rise some security alerts for the users, haven't checked what really happens).

Answer (score 5):

You can also change one character in your config/initializers/secret_token.rb