# Ruby on Rails: no implicit conversion of Array into String (DEVISE)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, osx-mavericks, ruby-2.1

I recently upgraded to OSX Mavericks 10.9 from 10.7, and since then it has been causing me lots of troubles. I upgraded Xcode, Command line tools, reinstalled homebrew and rvm, and finally got rails s to work (I spent a good 5 hours getting rmagick to work again).

However, now when I try to access my app from my localhost, I get this error

```
no implicit conversion of Array into String
```

Here is the rails log:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-05 02:20:00 -0700
Processing by AccountsController#dashboard as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0.3ms

TypeError (no implicit conversion of Array into String):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:26:in `check_correct_subdomain'


  Rendered /Users/kibaek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@onvard/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/kibaek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@onvard/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/kibaek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@onvard/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (7.1ms)
```

This is application_controller.rb where the error is getting called:

```
  def check_correct_subdomain
    if current_user
      redirect_to root_url(subdomain: current_user.account.domain) if request.subdomain != current_user.account.domain
    end
  end
```

Here are my versions:

```
Kibaeks-MacBook-Pro:onvard_saas kibaek$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
Kibaeks-MacBook-Pro:onvard_saas kibaek$ rails -v 
Rails 3.2.16
Kibaeks-MacBook-Pro:onvard_saas kibaek$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.5.1
Kibaeks-MacBook-Pro:onvard_saas kibaek$ rvm -v
rvm 1.25.25 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

- We were on rails 3.2.16 and ruby 2.1.0 prior to my mavericks upgrade as well. i just reinstalled homebrew, rvm and rails/ruby to the same version.

I pushed this to the staging server, and my other developer says it is working locally on his machine, so I think it may have been something I did in the process of upgrading to Mavericks or copy+pasting a bunch of stuff while trying to fix the imagemagick/rmagick error..

*I'm able to access my other rails projects, just get this no implicit conversion error on this particular app all of a sudden.

Is there any particular reason that I would be getting this error on my local machine, when the other developers don't get it? (I'm thinking it's my local settings that are causing the issue, not the code)

---

Edit: This turned out to be a devise issue with sessions. I was able to solve it through [Devise upgrade from 1.1.5 to 1.4.5 causes Wrong Number of Arguments error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404313/devise-upgrade-from-1-1-5-to-1-4-5-causes-wrong-number-of-arguments-error)

Comment: Aside from the conversion error, you should really upgrade to Rails 3.2.17 ASAP, to pick up the security fixes from last Februrary. See http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2014/2/18/Rails_3_2_17_4_0_3_and_4_1_0_beta2_have_been_released/.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for the answers! So it seems like it was a problem with the sessions that was causing the error..

I was able to solve this by following [Devise upgrade from 1.1.5 to 1.4.5 causes Wrong Number of Arguments error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404313/devise-upgrade-from-1-1-5-to-1-4-5-causes-wrong-number-of-arguments-error)

I ran `rake tmp:clear` and changed the name of the key in the session_store.rb file.

Wow I spent 14 hours trying to solve this issue and it turns out there was such an easy solution..

Answer (score 0):

It appears that both of the following in your code are evaluating arrays:

```
if current_user
if affiliate
```

Calling if on an array will give you this error.

I am unsure why you would have current_user as an array unless you are setting it somewhere else in your code, check anywhere you have current_user =

For affiliate, find_by_token is returning an array, perhaps try one of the following:

```
if affiliate.present?
if !affiliate.nil?
```