# Reset password for devise rails gives 'no implicit conversion of Array into String' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, passwords, ruby-on-rails-5, forgot-password

I'm trying to be able to reset a password the default devise passwords controller #create method and I am receiving an error when Devise tries to generate a token. This is breaking in development using rails server.

I am not customizing the passwords controller, I'm simply working with the default devise controller for this method.

I've tried searching and I haven't found similar issues, except [Ruby on Rails: no implicit conversion of Array into String (DEVISE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469084/ruby-on-rails-no-implicit-conversion-of-array-into-string-devise) which does not appear related. I tried clearing the rails cache and working with an incognito browser, but this didn't change anything. I'm now looking for other things to try but seem to be hitting a brick wall.

Configuration:

Devise to use username for authentication rather than email:

```
config.authentication_keys = [:username]
config.reset_password_keys = [:username]
```

And my user is subclassed as "User::Admin" etc. and it looks like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates :username, uniqueness: true
  validates :user_type, presence: true
  self.inheritance_column = :user_type
```

[Image of Final Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWwcw.png)

My log with stack trace:

```
Started POST "/users/password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-16 14:27:44         -0700
Processing by Users::PasswordsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    "authenticity_token"=>"rS7qFIRbbpd/M3QoAD1OLeDRDoliWAQK+PRE/qG2CgK2COvwwVCNFA6aMpcY0P81AEKo0fEpfNe4SRqLk7WDAw==", "user"=>{"username"=>"timtim"}, "commit"=>"Send me reset password instructions"}
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["username", "timtim"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/timchipperfield/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)


TypeError (no implicit conversion of Array into String):

/Users/timchipperfield/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/openssl/pkcs5.rb:14:in `pbkdf2_hmac'
/Users/timchipperfield/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/openssl/pkcs5.rb:14:in `pbkdf2_hmac'
/Users/timchipperfield/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/openssl/pkcs5.rb:19:in `pbkdf2_hmac_sha1'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:23:in `generate_key'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:38:in `generate_key'
devise (4.4.3) lib/devise/token_generator.rb:29:in `key_for'
devise (4.4.3) lib/devise/token_generator.rb:17:in `generate'
devise (4.4.3) lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:90:in `set_reset_password_token'
devise (4.4.3) lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:51:in `send_reset_password_instructions'
devise (4.4.3) lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:136:in `send_reset_password_instructions'
devise (4.4.3) app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb:15:in `create'
```

There is lots more to the stack trace "before" it hits the controller if that helps.

I'm running devise (4.4.3) with Passenger as my Application Server

my env look like:

```
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]
Rails 5.2.0
Bundler version 1.16.2
rvm 1.29.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Rails 5.2.0, I guess you also replaced `secret_key_base` with `encrypted credentials`. However, by default devise still tries to use secret_key_base for generating a secure hash.

You should be getting an error similar to this:

```
TypeError in User::PasswordsController#create
no implicit conversion of Hash into String

def pbkdf2_hmac(pass, salt, iter, keylen, digest)
  OpenSSL::KDF.pbkdf2_hmac(pass, salt: salt, iterations: iter,
                               length: keylen, hash: digest)
end
```

There are two options to fix this issue:

1) Uncomment `config.secret_key` in initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.secret_key = 'SOME_RANDOM_VALUE'
```

2) Add that `SOME_RANDOM_VALUE` to encrypted_credentials:

Firstly run:

```
rails credentials:edit
```

Add a line similar to this:

```
devise:
  secret_key: SOME_RANDOM_VALUE
```

Then call that key from the devise initializer:

```
config.secret_key = Rails.application.credentials.devise[:secret_key]
```

Comment: This works. Thanks for the fantastic, detailed answer  @msdundar.